# How can I be sure that google in app payments will work when the version is published on the store?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I've been testing google in-app payments and they work well on the debug version and on the internal track by adding the license testers.

If I try with an account that isn't registered as a licensed tester I get:

> This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

Does this mean that not everything is configured correctly or will it work correctly when I publish it on the play store?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the app from the store and everything worked great